# Visual Studio Setting: Invoke directly sub/nested class (omit parent Class)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, class

E.g.

I have a class:

```
Namespace Common

Public Class AClass

  Public Class BClass
  'some code

  End Class

End Class
```

How can I use BClass without saying AClass.BClass, I've see some existing code using this format, but I can't find the setting.

can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to have the BClass inside the AClass? Why not just put it in the Common namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any Visual Studio setting to accomplish what you are trying to do. However, you could use an alias to enable you to reference `AClass.BClass` using just `BClass`. I'm a C# guy, but Google says that in VB.NET it would be something like `Imports BClass = Common.AClass.BClass`.

Having said that, if it's code under your control, I would just not create `BClass` as a nested type.